# Empty Rows in listview

Tags: android, listview

whenever I add a new value in an array it creates two rows with one empty row in listview. when i delete a value in array the value is removed but both row still exists.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listcontact);               sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(preferences,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for(int i=1;i<=n+1;i++) {
        String st=sharedPreferences.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        conact_list.add(st);
        }
ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,conact_list);
ListView cv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
cv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I have checked arraylist and arrayadapter both doesnt have empty value or extra size but in list view it displays as follow :
[image]

**Log:**

> 04-25 12:40:31.491  30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack
>   D/ERR﹕ entered 04-25 12:40:31.501 
>   30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕ + 04-25
>   12:40:31.501  30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕
>   +93838394 04-25 12:40:31.501  30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕ +947574748 04-25
>   12:40:31.501  30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕
>   +87478494 04-25 12:40:31.501  30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕ aA
>   created[93838394, 947574748, 87478494] 04-25 12:40:31.501 
>   30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕ lv3count3list
>   view count:0 04-25 12:40:31.501 
>   30892-30892/com.symbols.syedibrahim.phonetrack D/ERR﹕ la

Comment: have you checked your shared preference file ..?

Comment: check if sharedPerference is empty, use `st.isEmpty()`  eg : `for(int i=1;i<=n+1;i++) {
        String st=sharedPreferences.getString(String.valueOf(i), "");
        if( ! st.isEmpty() ) {
           conact_list.add(st);}
        }`

Comment: It looks like your SharedPreferences are not populated as you expect, so you are getting the default empty String.

Comment: if my shared preference is wrong ,my array will have empty values. but my array and array adapter has exact right values and no empty values.

Comment: Take Log for each iteration. and show us the log.

Comment: use some pastie site boy like http://paste.ofcode.org, paste log there and share url here. :-)

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/H6EtPi3SHw5LMZMxCYp3hN
sorry about rough coding, array is displayed in braces. value after lv is array value , value after count is array adapter value

Comment: Is that all ? The list is having only 4 data ?

Comment: 3 data actually , exactly same thing in the picture. but i dont know why the empty rows are formed in listview.

Comment: what is that "n" value ?

Comment: 8, but array shows only 3 value, how is that possible

Comment: See, you can't just iterate over any random value, it should be limited to size of the array.

Comment: sorry to disturb you guys,this type of shared preference was too confusing. so i stored it as set and retrieved it as set in shared preference . but my real problem was onResume(),silly of me. and sorry for not giving proper details to you guys. I was trying to solve this for 2 days. you guys made my day thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my opinion:

**Case 1**: Check the number of data object is matching with your item in the view. It mean in `for(int i=1;i<=n+1;i++` we check the value of n, does it equal to the number items displayed in the view.
If two values are same, you should check you data in preference again.

**Otherwise, go to case 2** : check your adapter, in adapter you should check `getView` and `getCount` method. The number value returned by `getCount` must be same with number of data object.

Comment: I doubt if there is any method named as `onCreateView` in adapter.

Comment: Sorry for my misstake. I mean getView function